# Binary Search Tree removal using recursion

Tags: ios, swift, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

When removing a node from a binary search tree, you either replace the node with its biggest child on the left or its smallest child on the right.

I'm having a hard time understanding the way the following [implementation](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/blob/e592ed665973fda36df3efa6d7c20ee08705d8db/Binary%20Search%20Tree/Solution%201/BinarySearchTree.playground/Sources/BinarySearchTree.swift#L107) executes the the removal operation.

```swift
@discardableResult public func remove() -> BinarySearchTree? {
  let replacement: BinarySearchTree?

  // Replacement for current node can be either biggest one on the left or
  // smallest one on the right, whichever is not nil
  if let right = right {
    replacement = right.minimum()
  } else if let left = left {
    replacement = left.maximum()
  } else {
    replacement = nil
  }

  // Recursion
  replacement?.remove()

  // Place the replacement on current node's position
  replacement?.right = right
  replacement?.left = left
  right?.parent = replacement
  left?.parent = replacement
  reconnectParentTo(node:replacement)

  // The current node is no longer part of the tree, so clean it up.
  parent = nil
  left = nil
  right = nil

  return replacement
}
```

The above code consists of following steps:

1. Find a replacement node.
2. Have the replacement node refer the removed node's right and left child.
3. Have the right and the left child of the removed node refer to the replacement node as a parent.
4. Have the replacement node refer to the removed node's parent as its own parent.
5. Clean up.

The part I'm having difficulty specifically is the recursion.  As far as I understand, the base case of the recursion is `replacement = nil` because as long as there is either a right child or a left child, the recursion will continue to occur.  However, how can `replacement` be `nil` when it's supposed to refer for the replacement node? At the same time, how does the recursion stop if `replacement` isn't `nil`?

Comment: If the current node has neither left nor right children (ie it is a leaf) then there is nothing to replace it with - `replacement = nil`.  When replacement is `nil` `replacement?.remove()` does nothing, so recursion ends.

Comment: But, my understanding is that the whole point of the recursion is to find the replacement node so that the parent, right and the left children of the replacement node can be fulfilled with the removed node. If the replacement is nil, doesn't it defeat the purpose of finding the replacement node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help to see what happens visually.  Let's say you start with this tree and want to remove the orange root node

[image]

You call `remove` on the orange node:

- `self` is *orange*.
- `replacement` is the minimum of the right subtree - the blue node.

You recurse by calling `remove` on blue:

- `self` is *blue*
- `replacement` is nil as *blue* has neither left nor right children
- You call `remove` on `nil` (or rather you don't, because of the ?)
- Similarly, all of the other assignments are skipped because the optional values are all `nil`
- `reconnectParent(node: nil)` is called to fix the left/right linkage of blue's parent (this will result in `green.left` being assigned `nil`)
- You return *blue*

The tree now looks like:

[image]

You are now back out at the initial call to `remove` and execution continues.  Remember,

- `self` is *orange*.
- `replacement` is *blue* node.

The next steps are:

- `blue.right = orange.right`
- `blue.left = orange.left`
- `orange.right.parent = blue`
- `orange.left.parent = blue`
- `orange.reconnectParentTo(node:blue)` - This does nothing since `orange` has no parent
- `orange.parent = nil`
- `orange.right = nil`
- `orange.left = nil`
- Return from `remove` - This was the initial call to `remove`, so we have exited all recursion

This leaves us with the final tree:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This makes it so much clearer to me. The fact that `replacement = nil` is not only used for the base case of the recursion, but also in `reconnectParentTo` to sever the ties with the parent node was hard to wrap my head around.